# ASP.NET debugger gives errors with http, while working with https

Tags: asp.net, debugging, syntax-error

I really desperately need your help because I got very unusual problem with my programs:

1. I am receiving this error when I am trying to debug my ASP.NET or MVC Application on local IIS Server 7.5:
   "Unable to start debugging on the web server. The debug request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax. "

   [image]
2. I tried literally every solution I could find in google until this day. I spent 12 hours trying to figure this out. Without luck.
3. Error happens only with this address: http:// localhost/AspDemo not with this one: https:// localhost/AspDemo. Basically, I can debug like always if I put https instead of http.
4. https is disabled on my local IIS server :), I mean it is set to ignore.
5. Moreover I CAN open my sites with using BOTH protocols in IIS Control Panel
6. If I disable ASP.NET Debugger in Properties of my App in Visual Studio, Application runs fine.
7. This is the error from the httperr log:

   **2014-10-30 00:23:46 ::1%0 2977 ::1%0 80 - - - 400 - Verb -**
8. I am not sure where exactly, but in some other log I saw reference to something like this: **Error 400 "Bad Request - Invalid Verb"**
9. A week ago ALL applications I got problems with were working perfectly with asp.net debugger from visual studio, I had no idea what happened.
10. I suspect some update. Because updates lately messed with my custom bootloader as well.
11. When I enable tracing - log is empty with http
12. Fiddler log is empty as well, maybe there is some config I can use in Fiddler to produce some more logs? (It logs of course with modified machine.config when I use https)

Would be eternally grateful for your help, if you need some more logs, please don't hestitate to ask.

I would like to mention as well that yes, I saw similar posts on this  site, but none of them described problem this similar to mine.

/edit

From what I was able to observe, error happens BEFORE debugger access machine.config file, can you guys tell me how to catch errors in that moment?

**==== /edit 2 ====**

Anyone? No one knows the answer?
Recently I was able to find the complete error message in: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\Visual Studio Web Debugger.log

```
http://localhost/MVCDemo/debugattach.aspx

Status code=400 (Bad Request)
Protocol version=1.1
Cached=False
Connection=close
Content-Length=326
Content-Type=text/html; charset=us-ascii
Date=Fri, 31 Oct 2014 03:44:14 GMT
Server=Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

In proccess monitor, I found this one as well:

```
<event>
<ProcessIndex>1339</ProcessIndex>
<Time_of_Day>04:40:33,3661553</Time_of_Day>
<Process_Name>devenv.exe</Process_Name>
<PID>10768</PID>
<Operation>CreateFile</Operation>
<Path>C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Debugger\StepIntoFilterData.ini</Path>
<Result>PATH NOT FOUND</Result>
<Detail>Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Read Attributes, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a</Detail>
</event>
```

I really, really need help with this.

**=== /edit 3 ===**

Second error is not relevant, I just checked and it is present with https as well (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Debugger\StepIntoFilterData.in), and debugging as https localhost works perfectly.

**=== /edit 4 ===**

Here are Process Monitor logs captured during Visual Studio Debugging HTTP (not working) and HTTPS (working)

(Test performed on random MVC Tutorial)

Use CTRL+F and Look for "Visual Studio Web Debugger.log" in logs to get the idea when it is happening. In https log is good, in http log returns Invalid Verb error mentioned before.

- HTTP (not working)::
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/7b26ybogtyqlico/LogFile%20HTTP%20NOT%20Working.CSV?dl=0
- HTTPS (working):
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ggsj57v97ky90e6/LogFile%20HTTPS%20Working.CSV?dl=0

**I might be wrong, but I think the key here is that only HTTP doesn't work and only with VS Debugger, everything else is just fine (HTTP and HTTPS without debugging and HTTPS with debugging.)**

(It happens with every solution on IIS, new ones are affected too, all of these solutions were working, moreover some of them were not even changed from the time they have been working, IIS config didn't change as well)

Comment: Try running Visual Studio as an administrator.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I run ALWAYS as administrator, I tried even to run as system, did you read the errors I mentioned, do they give you guys any clue?

Comment: I'm curious where this is coming from: `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\...` If that value is being read somewhere from something that should be XML, it would certainly be invalid syntax. Can you do a full-project text search for `<UserName>` and see if that yields any results in any files? Particularly in solution, project, config files.

Comment: I checked via Process Monitor, and when I am using https instead of http, the same file is being reported as missing, but everything works perfectly, so it is not the case as I thought I am going to post entire report soon. I want to mention again that both protocols are working when starting app manually from IIS Server using Browse option.

Comment: Did you run Fiddler as administrator?

Comment: I did, but to be honest I don't know fiddler much, I just modified machine.config, tested https, fiddler returned 200, no errors, 443 port, http: nothing was returned. But I might have no idea about this program :). So If I need to use any additional options, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the name of the verb in any of the description here, but my guess is VS debugger using a special verb (DEBUG) rather than the standard GET, HEAD, POST, etc. If you re-installed IIS after VS, the ISAPI mapping probably got nuked. This may solve the problem:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165022%28v=vs.90%29.aspx